# Как пристроить резидентную программу в Linux?

Tags: linux, systemd

Многие программы вроде серверов работают в системе постоянно, запускаясь с ней автоматически и перезапускаясь в случае сбоя. Но каким образом производится внедрение такой программы в Linux? Наверняка ведь не ограничиваются простым `nohup a.run &`.

Comment: man systemd почитайте

Comment: @gbg, то есть этого вполне достаточно?

Comment: Именно эта подсистема решает вашу задачу в современных линуксах

Comment: Добрые люди [уже подробно ответили](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17955149/7286264) до нас

Comment: @gbg, понял, спасибо!

Comment: @avp, ох, благодарю, не додумался загуглить именно «daemon»

Comment: fork-detach-fork